# Weird change of variables (?) I would like to understand formally

Tags: calculus, probability, change-of-variable

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf) paper (bottom of p. 4), the authors state the following (I've added all definitions below):

> Given the deterministic mapping $z=g_{\phi}(\epsilon, x)$ we know that: $q_\phi (z|x)\Pi_i dz_i = p(\epsilon)\Pi_i d\epsilon_i$. Therefore, $$\int q_\phi(z|x)f(z)dz = \int p(\epsilon)f(z)d\epsilon=\int p(\epsilon)f(g_\theta(\epsilon, x))d\epsilon$$

where:

- $z$ is a continuous random variable from some conditional
  distribution: $z \sim q_\phi(z|x)$
- $z$ can be expressed using a deterministic, vector-valued function
  $g_\phi(\epsilon, x)$ parameterized by $\phi$ using $\epsilon \sim
     p(\epsilon)$. For example, for $z \sim N(\mu(x), \sigma(x)^2)$, we could write $z
     = \mu(x) + \sigma(x)\epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$.
- $f$ is some function.

I can't derive this *formally* (I can intuitively see how they plugged in the equality before the "Therefore," and that it 'kind of makes sense'). I was trying to see if I could somehow prove this using change of variables, but since $\epsilon$ is itself sampled, I don't see how that applies.

What is going on here, formally? (**Ideally - I would like to know which theorems are being used and how**).

This question was addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214011/reparametrization-trick), but not rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used some better notation. These are assumed:

$$f_Z(z)= q_\phi(z|x)$$
$$Z \sim g_{\phi}(\mathcal E, x)$$
$$f_{\mathcal E}(\epsilon)= p(\epsilon)$$

where $f_Z(z)$ and $f_{\mathcal E}(\epsilon)$ denote the pdfs of random variables $Z$ and $\mathcal E$, respectively. To avoid confusion, I here replace $f$ in the OP by $H$.

Then,

$$\int q_\phi(z|x)H(z)dz=\int f_Z(z)H(z)dz=\mathbb E [H(Z)]\\ =\mathbb E \big [H(\color{blue}{g_{\phi}(\mathcal E, x)}) \big ]=\int f_{\mathcal E}(\epsilon)H(g_\phi(\epsilon, x))d\epsilon=\int p(\epsilon)H(g_\phi(\epsilon, x))d\epsilon.$$

Comment: OK - this reduces the problem to showing that the two expectations are indeed equal (your third equality), which should be easy. Thanks!